# Sendmail is not listening to any port

Tags: centos, email-server, centos6, port, sendmail

I am using VPS hosting with CentOS 6.

I've installed **Sendmail**, but it's not listening to any port. I've checked, IPTables is disabled (or stopped I guess;    `service iptables status` command returns `iptables: Firewall is not running.`

Here is `netstat -plnt` output

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address      Foreign Address    State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22         0.0.0.0:*          LISTEN      1538/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25       0.0.0.0:*          LISTEN      1186/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306       0.0.0.0:*          LISTEN      11274/mysqld
tcp        0      0 :::22              :::*               LISTEN      1538/sshd
tcp        0      0 ::1:25             :::*               LISTEN      1186/master
tcp        0      0 :::80              :::*               LISTEN      14173/httpd
```

In sendmail.mc, I've edited `DAEMON_OPTIONS('Port=smtp,Addr=127.0.0.1, Name=MTA')dnl` **Addr** to 0.0.0.0 , and recreated the `.cf` file using `m4`,but that doesn't seem to solve the issue.

What should I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

CentOS 6 comes with Postfix as default mail server and you can see it running (tcp :25 1186/master).
Try to stop Postfix (`service postfix stop`) and then start sendmail (`service sendmail start`).